# Removed WPtouch but still in use

Tags: wordpress

I have removed WPTouch from my wordpress site (techwayz.com) but its still active .I can see googlebots being redirected to normal view of my website . Here's the sample link that googlebot visited http://example.com/?wptouch_view=normal&wptouch_redirect_nonce= ... . I have completely removed the WP touch plugin and have even emptied the cache but its not working.What can i do to to disable this wptouch redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you learned the hard way that a responsive design is better than a mobile site…

Create a plugin that catches `$_GET['wptouch_view']` and other wptouch parameters, strip them from the URL, and redirect to the relevant page with a 301. They'll eventually go away.

Answer (score 0):

IF the plugin isn't there anymore you don't need to worry about, they will disappear in no time (and if they don't they will not hurt).

It looks like only a query string and if you're not having 404 errors you will not have seo rankings affected - that would be the case for the 302 redirect as suggested.

Regards,

Auro